# Find out if logged in user is not subscriber

Tags: users, user-roles

Is there a conditional tag that will allow me to display certain content only if the user is NOT a subscriber?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<?php
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( ! user_can( $current_user, "subscriber" ) ) // Check user object has not got subscriber role
    echo 'User is a not Subscriber';
else
    echo 'User is a Subscriber';
?>
```

Answer (score 19):

An even more simple way, than @Brady showed you is the using [`current_user_can`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can):

```
if ( current_user_can( 'subscriber' ) )
    echo "Hi, dear subscriber! Glad seeing you again!";
```

#### MU

There's also an equivalent for MU installations, named [`current_user_can_for_blog`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can_for_blog):

```
global $blog_id;
if ( current_user_can_for_blog( $blog_id, 'subscriber' ) ) 
    echo "Hi, dear subscriber! Glad seeing you again on this blog!";
```

#### Behind the curtain

When looking at the source of the functions [for single](http://queryposts.com/function/current_user_can/) or [MU installations](http://queryposts.com/function/current_user_can_for_blog/), then you'll see, that both basically rely on [`wp_get_current_user()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_get_current_user/) and then do a check for `has_cap`.
Now if you want to see, where the cap comes from, then [`WP_User`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User#has_cap.28.24cap.29) class/object comes into the game.

#### Other members of this set

Then there's also `author_can( $GLOBALS['post'], 'capability' );`. All those functions are inside `~/wp-includes/capabilities` right below each other.

#### When to use what?

Now, where's the difference between `current_user_can(_FOR_BLOG)` and [`user_can`](http://queryposts.com/function/user_can/)?

- `user_can()` is the newer one (since 3.1), but needs the user as object. So you can use it in cases, where you don't want to target the current user, but *some* users.
- `current_user_can_*()` is obvious.
- `author_can()` allows you to check capabilities against a post object. This object is only available for posts, that are already in the DB. So it's mainly for allowing/denying  the access to specific post features.

Comment: This I feel needs to be updated, because:

***Do not** pass a role name to current_user_can(), as this is not guaranteed to work correctly (see [#22624](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22624)).*

from the [`current_user_can()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) codex page AFAIK hasn't changed.

Comment: @ialocin You can update that if you want (it's 2years+ old). You are basically right. On the other hand a role gets added as capability as well ;)

Comment: I guess this should actually be enough for a remark/update, besides I'm lazy...too ;)

Answer (score -3):

Is this what you mean?

```
global $userdata;
get_currentuserinfo();
if ( $userdata->user_level != 0 )//check user level by level ID
{
  echo 'User is a not Subscriber';
}
else
{
  echo 'User is a Subscriber';
}
```

More details on the ID's for different levels: http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#User_Levels

There is also the current_user_can() function, which lets you denote specific capabilities for more flexibility.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can

Comment: Don't use user levels... Here is what codex says about it: `To maintain backwards compatibility with plugins that still use the user levels system (although this is very much discouraged), the default Roles in WordPress also include Capabilities that correspond to these levels. User Levels were finally deprecated in version 3.0.`