# Do not execute If User is login as Administrator or any Specific Role

Tags: php, user-roles, users

How can I not execute some `<script> </script>` if the user is an administrator or any specific role?

Basically I need to do something like this:

```
    <?php if( !User( 'Administrator', 'Editor' ) ) {        
        <script> </script>        
    } ?>
```

Comment: This post will help you http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60272/find-out-if-logged-in-user-is-not-subscriber AND http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131814/if-current-user-is-admin-or-editor

Comment: And one more thing! You can't use `<script> tag` inside `<?php  ?>` (php tag)!! Before using `<script>` you need to close php tag first like this `?> <script> </script> <?php`.

Comment: @Rishabh The two post isn't working for my needs. I need to execute the script if the User is not "LogIn" and if the User is not an administrator. Could you give me a sample code?

Answer (score 0):

Solution, using and statement '&&' for another specific role.

Closing `<?php if() : ?>`, `<?php else : ?>` Tag with a Column : to be able to post scripts inside the Loop.

```
<?php
global $current_user; // Use global
get_currentuserinfo(); // Make sure global is set, if not set it.

if ( ! user_can( $current_user, "administrator") && ! user_can( $current_user, "specific_role" ) )  : ?> // Check user object has not got subscriber role
    <!-- Not Administrator -->
<?php else : ?>
    <!-- Administrator -->
<?php endif; ?>
```